# Enabling the second dropdown list if some values is selected in first dropdown - jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, dropdown

I have written the code but second drop down is not disabling when nothing is selected in first drop down. Second drop down is always enabled.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

```
$('#attribute1211').change(function(e){
    $('#attribute1219').prop('disabled', !$(this).val());
});



$(function(){
    $('#attribute1219').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```
<div id="product-options-wrapper" class="product-options">
<div class="opts-container">
    <div class="counter">1</div>
        <label class="required"><em>*</em>First Option</label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <select id="attribute1211" class="required-entry super-attribute-select" name="super_attribute[1211]">
                <option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
                <option value="1747" price="0" data-label="vinyl matt">Vinyl Matt</option>
                <option value="1748" price="0" data-label="vinyl silk">Vinyl Silk</option>
                <option value="1749" price="0" data-label="vinyl soft sheen">Vinyl Soft Sheen</option>
                <option value="1746" price="0" data-label="high gloss">High Gloss</option>
                <option value="1745" price="0" data-label="eggshell">Eggshell</option>
                <option value="1740" price="0" data-label="diamond eggshell">Diamond Eggshell</option>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="opts-container">
    <div class="counter">2</div>
    <label class="required"><em>*</em>Size</label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <select  id="attribute1219" class="required-entry super-attribute-select" name="super_attribute[1219]" >
            <option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
            <option value="1718" price="0" data-label="5 litre">5 Litre</option>
            <option value="1719" price="0" data-label="2.5 litre">2.5 Litre</option>
            <option value="1714" price="0" data-label="1 litre">1 Litre</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: working fine for me.see this https://jsfiddle.net/bwL409zx/

Comment: But i am trying in jsp page..it is not coming in jsp page: below is my code in jsp:

Comment: Jsp has nothing to do with it, don't blame them:) try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bwL409zx/1/)